# why is "advice" used as an uncountable noun and "suggestion" used as a countable noun?

Tags: nouns, countability

I think "advice" and "suggestion" are both abstract nouns. Then why is "**advice**" used as an **uncountable** noun and "**suggestion**" used as a **countable** noun?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a *why*. Language is basically a popularity contest: we're constantly 'voting' on how we want to use words, and right now *uncountable* leads the *advice* poll by a very large margin.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason "the pen" in Spanish is "la pluma", while "the pencil" is "el lápiz" instead of "la lápiz": **it sounds more natural to native speakers** (as StoneyB mentioned in the comment, we're 'voting' on how to use these words).

Note that if you mix these up you'll probably get a few funny looks, but you won't be misunderstood.

Comment: You could argue that it only sounds better to them because that's how they learned it...

Answer (score 2):

If you ask for advice, you really don't know how much advice you need, otherwise you'd probably wouldn't be asking for advice.  Advice when desired is usually not a precise, measured activity, the corporate world's abuse of the term *advise* notwithstanding (and even then, no guarantee that it's precise/measured there either).

When you ask for a suggestion, it's focused and directed on a certain thing, so it's measurable to a greater extent.  *Give me two suggestions on where to go* - the asker wants you to respond with two places.  *Give me advice on where to go* - the asker really isn't specifying the number of places, because he or she doesn't really know.  You could respond with *You need to go here* or *You need to go to place A, then place B, and finally place C.*